# Get Xcode Build Time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, build, compile-time

I want to extract the overall build time of an Xcode project displayed in the small box above Xcode if you enabled `defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode ShowBuildOperationDuration YES`.

[image]

I don't find any information in the `.xcactivitylog` files.

I also tried the approach to save the time via a build phase script at the very top, but including some pods this would need to be also in every pod as build phase script..

Does Xcode save this information somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case could be solved using scripts that runs before and after the build. You can set them up in Xcode -> Preferences -> Behaviors
[image: Xcode -> Preferences -> Behaviors]

On start you can assign:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo `date +%s` > test.txt
```

and on the end

```
#!/bin/sh
startTime=$(head -n 1 test.txt)
currentTime=`date +%s` 
diff="$(($currentTime - $startTime))"
# do whatever you need with compilation time
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [BuildTimeAnalyzer](https://github.com/RobertGummesson/BuildTimeAnalyzer-for-Xcode) for logging build time of every file and function. It is open source project, and you can check an implementation.

Comment: but this does not match with what Xcode says correct? As it only shows the compile time, not the overall build time :-(

Comment: Also you can check [BuildTimeLogger](https://github.com/marcinreliga/BuildTimeLogger-for-Xcode) with nice notification information about build time.

Answer (score 1):

-> Go to terminal
-> cd project directory

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode ShowBuildOperationDuration YES
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you need this for? There are alternative solutions (like using Trrminal and xcodebuild), but that depends on what you need this for.

**Update:** OK, you say you need this to measure build times across developers. In that case, I think the only API you can use is the Accessibility API to actually query Xcode's UI for values.

Comment: I want to get data across all developers in our team - they are using Xcode to build during development so unfortunately Terminal is not a solution for me :(